# Flipping the Grid

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

Suppose a grid of size N * M is having only 1 and 0. The rows are numbered from 1 to N, and the columns are numbered from 1 to M.

Following steps can be called as a single move.

1. Select two integers x,y (1<=x<=N and 1<=y<=M) i.e. one square on the matrix.
2. All the integers in the rectangle denoted by (1,1) and (x,y) i.e. rectangle having top-left and bottom-right points as (1,1) and (x,y) are toggled(1 is made 0 and 0 is made 1).

Like suppose the initial grid with N=4 and M =3 is :

101
110
101
000

Now, if we choose x=3 and y=2, the new state of grid would be

011
000
011
000

For a given state of grid, the aim of the game is to reduce the matrix to a state where all numbers are 1. What is minimum number of moves required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the order of flips does not matter, just the list of $(x,y)$ points that are the lower right corners of flips.  You might as well start from the lower right corner.  Flip $(N,M)$ if required.  Now check $(N-1,M)$ and $(N,M-1)$ and flip what is required.  Work your way up to $(1,1)$.  The worst case is a checkerboard with $0$ in $(N,M)$, which will force you to $NM$ flips.

Comment: If i flip (N,M) then it will flip all the numbers from (1,1) to ( N,M).And moreover i have to find minimum moves. Are you sure that your approach will give minimum move as result? Please explain

Comment: Yes, because you have to flip $(N,M)$ if it starts $0$ and only a flip of $(N,M)$ will fix it.  After you have flipped it or not, the only flip that touches $(N,M-1)$ is that one, so you do that or not.  Think about $$\begin {array}\\ 0&1\\1&0 \end {array}$$  This will take four flips

Comment: Ya..u r right..got u know